# What is the meaning of `typename` in this example?

Tags: c++, templates

I was looking at an example implementation of `binder1st`, that looks like this:

```
template <class Operation, class T>
  binder1st<Operation> bind1st (const Operation& op, const T& x)
{
  return binder1st<Operation>(op, typename Operation::first_argument_type(x));
}
```

What is the meaning of `typename Operation::first_argument_type(x)`. I understand `first_argument_type` to be a typename, but belonging to the `binary_function` base class. It looks to me that it is a function belonging to namespace `Operation` - in which case, why is `typename` used here?

Comment: It's not a function, but a function-style cast to the type `Operation::first_argument_type`.

Comment: Is a function-style cast the same thing as what Stefano describes below ( the constructor of `Operation::first_argument_type`, taking a `const T&`)?

Comment: @BeeBand Yes, the function-style cast is invoking the constructor.

Comment: @BeeBand Yes, but depending on exact types, appropriate `T::operator Type()` could also be called.

Comment: Ok great, I was just wondering what the purpose of this cast was - it seems that this is to verify during compilation that `Operation` has the nested typedef of `first_argument_type`.

Answer (score 0):

it means that the qualified name that follows the `typename` keyword (i.e. `Operation::first_argument_type`) is to be interpreted as the name of a (dependent) type.

You can read the full explanation of the keyword `typename` (which also has another, different usage) [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html#real_reason).

Comment: In this context, is `x` being cast to the type `Operation::first_argument_type`?

Comment: nope, the `Operation::first_argument_type` constructor taking a `const T&` argument is being invoked.

Comment: slightly off topic, read here http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/ , as it could be interesting. For example, I would write typename Operation::first_argument_type((x)), just to play on the safe side